# NegativeFillColor not working in stacked area highcharts graph

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to fill the color above the top series with particular color and I am using "negativeFillColor" for that, but somehow it doesn't seems to be working

**[CHECK FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/developer_fiddle/y2pLm/)**

**Relevant Code**

```
 series: [{
                name: 'Asia',
                data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268],
                threshold:10,
                negativeFillColor:'#F00',
                fillColor         : '#F7D358',
            }, ...]
```

What do I need to add or change here.  ? or is it somekind of bug...?

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work? You set theshold to 10, and have values higher than 500. For example set to 1000 and see how it works.

Comment: @PawełFus check edited fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/developer_fiddle/y2pLm/2/ .. I was expecting it to cover the upper portion of area with red color but instead it is filling the inner area with red

Comment: Yes, that's how stacked charts works. How about using `stacking:'percent'` instead? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/y2pLm/3/

Comment: @PawełFus I will give it a try .Thanks . Is it possible to extend the area colors to cover whole plotarea while using "tickmarkplacement":"between" so that area on extreme margins are not left white

Comment: You know, editing comment won't display notification.. :) In general, there is some question about categories and extending graph to the edges, just search a little SO.